# How to deep clone interconnected objects in C#?

Tags: c#, clone

What is the best way to **deep** clone an interconnected set of objects?  Example:

```
class A {
    B theB; // optional
    // ...
}

class B {
    A theA; // optional
    // ...
}

class Container {
    A[] a;
    B[] b;
}
```

The obvious thing to do is walk the objects and deep clone everything as I come to it. This creates a problem however -- if I clone an `A` that contains a `B`, and that `B` is also in the `Container`, that `B` will be cloned twice after I clone the `Container`.

The next logical step is to create a `Dictionary` and look up every object before I clone it. This seems like it could be a slow and ungraceful solution, however.

Any thoughts?

Comment: here's how I do it: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Deep%20Cloning&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not an elegant solution for sure, but it isn't uncommon to use a dictionary (or hashmap). One of the benefits is that a hashmap has a constant lookup time, so speed does not really suffer here.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary solution you suggested is the best I know of. To optimize further, you could use `object.GetHashCode()` to get a hash for the object, and use that as the dictionary key. Should be fast unless you're talking about huge object trees (10s to 100s of thousands of objects).

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am familiar with C#, but typically any type of crawling of a graph for some sort of processing will require a lookup table to stop processing an object due to cyclic references.  So I would think you will need to do the same here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe create a bit flag to indicate whether this object has been cloned before.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution you could investigate is serializing the objects into a stream, and then reconstructing them from that same stream into new instances. This often works wonders when everything else seems awfully convoluted and messy.

Marc

Comment: Can you elaborate? How could I prevent serialiizing the same object twice? Or if I just serialize "Container", how could I store *references* to A and B instead of the entire object, to avoid duplication? I can't just use a simple index like you would believe from the simple example.

Comment: WCF supports this with some tweaking (http://blogs.msdn.com/sowmy/archive/2006/03/26/561188.aspx). But serialization, while quick to code, is going to perform much worse than an explicit deep copy.

Comment: True - serializing and deserializing again might not be top in terms of performance. This comes down to the eternal "it depends" scenario :-) Do you need top performance and do you do this hundred of thousands of times in a loop --> then serializing might not be the best route to take.

Answer (score 0):

One of the practical ways to do deep cloning is serializing and then deserializing a source graph. Some serializers in .NET like [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) are even [capable of processing cycles within graphs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh241056(v=vs.100).aspx). You can choose which serializer is the best choice for your scenario by looking at [the feature comparison chart](http://manski.net/2014/10/net-serializers-comparison-chart/).